# jtree high DPI does not scale

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a java swing application using JTree.
I recently moved to a UHD monitor, and now the JTree doesn't scale nicely.
I have the feeling it uses the icon to scale the line-height, but have no clue how to influence this myself.
Please be aware that if `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` is being left out, it is unreadably small on the new monitor.
Please see screenshots / simple example code below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class JTreeTest extends JFrame
{

   private JPanel contentPane;

   /**
    * Launch the application.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         public void run()
         {
            try {
               // Set System L&F
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                     UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
               JTreeTest frame = new JTreeTest();
               frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }

   /**
    * Create the frame.
    */
   public JTreeTest()
   {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      setContentPane(contentPane);

      JTree tree = new JTree();
      contentPane.add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

}
```

normal resolution jtree screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4fUe.png]

UHD resolution jtree screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvXMf.png]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use [JTree#setRowHeight(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setRowHeight-int-)

> public void setRowHeight(int rowHeight)
>
> Sets the height of each cell, in pixels. If the specified value is less than or equal to zero the current cell renderer is queried for each row's height.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTreeTest2 extends JFrame
{
  private JPanel contentPane;

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          // Set System L&F
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
          JFrame frame = new JTreeTest2();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public JTreeTest2()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.setFont(tree.getFont().deriveFont(32f));

    JTree tree2 = new JTree();
    tree2.setFont(tree2.getFont().deriveFont(32f));
    tree2.setRowHeight(32);
    //or: tree2.setRowHeight(0);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(tree2));

    contentPane.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
  }
}
```